# JPA find by foreign key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Municipios")
public class Municipio {
    @Id
    private String nombreMunicipio;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "nombreProvincia", nullable = false)
    private Provincia nombreProvincia;        
}
```

how would I go about getting all the Municipios given the string ID of the province? what would the controller and repository look like? I've been trying for hours and can't find the answer

Edit: decided to post my repository and controller

```
public interface MunicipioRepo extends JpaRepository<Municipio, Integer> {
    
    boolean existsByNombreMunicipio(String nombreMunicipio);
    Municipio findByNombreMunicipio(String nombreMunicipio);
    List<Municipio> findAllByNombreProvincia(final Provincia provincia);
}



@GetMapping("/municipiosenprovincia")
    public List<Municipio> getMunicipiosEnProvincia(@RequestParam String nombreProvincia){
        System.out.printf(nombreProvincia);
        Optional<Provincia> miProv = provinciaRepo.findById(nombreProvincia);
        return municipioRepo.findAllByNombreProvincia(miProv.get());
    }
```

Comment: You have to write a JPQL which select all Municipios from the provinceID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that primary key of `Provincia` is `id`:

```
public interface MunicipioRepo extends JpaRepository<Municipio, Integer> {
    ...
    List<Municipio> findAllByNombreProvinciaId(final String provinciaId);
}
```

And just pass `provinciaId` to this method:

```
// getMunicipiosEnProvincia method in controller
...
return municipioRepo.findAllByNombreProvinciaId(nombreProvincia); // here nombreProvincia is the id of Provincia
```

Comment: This worked! the id of province is also NombreProvincia so the repository function has to be called findAllByNombreProvinciaNombreProvincia().

Comment: Glad to help :)